# Error -> java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, macos, maven

I've generated a project from spring boot generator. But I'm not able to resolve the dependency in the below code.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I'm trying to run this class I'm getting this error **java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist**

Here's my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've tried multiple solutions but nothing helped. Could it be because of some settings.xml file in my macbook? Is there a solution?

Comment: Maybe Maven is not able to download packages for some reason e.g. you didn't define proxy inside settings.xml? Check ~/.m2 folder if there is org.springframework... and so on. It should exist if the packages have been downloaded.

Comment: Please keep the version of the spring-boot-maven-plugin and your used parent version for spring boot in sync... best is to remove the version definition from your build because it's automatically defined by the parent which you are using....

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Intellij was to go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven
Make sure that the "Maven home path" points to the latest Maven version

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error, but I had newer version of spring-boot-starter-parent. I resolved my problem. My answer is most of all no longer relevant for you for today, but I hope it helps others, who will face with this issue.

I went in IntelliJ IDEA to File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Maven and changed there Maven home path from Use maven wrapper to Bundled (Maven 3). I guess it was due to wrapper for maven, because generated project had some maven wrapper files inside its structure by default.